# rails deployment with jenkins extremly slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, jenkins, bundler

I use Jenkins to test and deploy a Rails 3 application. It fetches the source from a SVN repo, then runs:

```
bundle install --deployment
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
rake spec
```

The process is very slow, it takes more than an hour (!), when locally `bundle install --deployment` takes 3 minutes. I run `ps aux` on the server during the bundling process and it doesn't seem to be overloaded. What could be the cause of such strange behaviour? How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with running Jenkins in the background (and/or as a service). Try running it in the foreground with `java -jar jenkins.war` an see if it helps.

Comment: It was a problem with Jenkins. Administraive work (probably java restart) solved the problem. Might have it been related to the [leap second bug](http://blog.wpkg.org/2012/07/01/java-leap-second-bug-30-june-1-july-2012-fix/)?